# VB6 recordset and SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb6

Assume I have main procedure `X` which will call four sub-procedures through VB 6.0 application via ADODB recordset.

E.g assume the names of the sub-procedures are `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

Out of the 4 sub-procedures, the first procedure `A` delete records from many tables and then the control passes to other 3 procedures. After migration all stored procedures from Oracle to SQL Server I am facing a problem, i.e. when I execute the main procedure through VB6 recordset that time procedure `A` sometimes does not delete records from tables and passing control to other procedures without proper execution.

Due to this I am not able to understand is it problem of locking mechanism of SQL Server or VB6 application recordset problem.

In existing old structure is works properly with VB6 and Oracle database.

My vb code given below

```vb
ST = "execute proc X"

Set adoPrimaryRS = New ADODB.Recordset
adoPrimaryRS.Open ST, db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

Sample code of Procedure X and A

PROCEDURE X

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[X]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXECUTE A 
        EXECUTE B 
        EXECUTE C 
        EXECUTE D 

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER$ INT;
            DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE$ VARCHAR(MAX);
            DECLARE @ERRORLINE$ INT;
            DECLARE @ERRORPROCEDURE$ VARCHAR(MAX);

            SET @ERRORNUMBER$ = ERROR_NUMBER();
            SET @ERRORMESSAGE$ = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            SET @ERRORLINE$ = ERROR_LINE();
            SET @ERRORPROCEDURE$ = ERROR_PROCEDURE();

            PRINT 'ERROR NUMBER : ' + CAST(@ERRORNUMBER$ AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ERROR MESSAGE : '+@ERRORMESSAGE$+', ERROR LINE NO. : '+ CAST(@ERRORLINE$ AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ERROR PROCEDURE : '+@ERRORPROCEDURE$;
            THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

PROCEDURE A

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM TABLE_1

        DELETE FROM TABLE_2

        DELETE FROM TABLE_3

        DELETE FROM TABLE_4            

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT WORK;

    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER$ INT;
        DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE$ VARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @ERRORLINE$ INT;
        DECLARE @ERRORPROCEDURE$ VARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @ERRORNUMBER$ = ERROR_NUMBER();
        SET @ERRORMESSAGE$ = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        SET @ERRORLINE$ = ERROR_LINE();
        SET @ERRORPROCEDURE$ = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'ERROR NUMBER : ' + CAST(@ERRORNUMBER$ AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ERROR MESSAGE : '+@ERRORMESSAGE$+', ERROR LINE NO. : '+CAST(@ERRORLINE$ AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ERROR PROCEDURE : '+@ERRORPROCEDURE$;
            THROW;
        END
    END CATCH
END;
```

Comment: What does a VBA `Recordset` have to do with VB.NET? Please edit your question to explain what you're actually doing or change the tags to those that actually apply.

Comment: VB6 is not VB.NET. Please tag your question accurately. Also please add some punctuation and spacing to your question - you have written one enormous sentence in the middle which is unreadable and barely makes sense. I'm sure this is not how you communicate with people normally, so please take the time to make it clear - otherwise people will have a hard time helping you. Thanks.

Comment: If `X` is a stored procedure, then it cannot call other procedures "via ADODB recordset". Please show the code of `X`.

Comment: as per your suggestion i put code please check and if possible help me

Answer (score 1):

This is how I execute a Stored Procedure via ADO in VB6:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = <your ADO connection here>
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

cmd.CommandText = "<name of the stored procedure>"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

With passing a parameter to a SP:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = <your ADO connection here>
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("ID", adInteger, adParamInput)
prm.Value = lID

cmd.CommandText = "<name of the stored procedure>"
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: This should work. Recordset is only for select. We can use recordset for select targeting table or view.